# Configure Sharepoint 2013 Excel Services REST API HTML representation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have an AddIn for Microsoft Word that consumes the Excel Services REST API to get a table, and then add it to the current document.

The AddIn works perfectly with Sharepoint 2010, but when update to Sharepoint 2013, the AddIn does not works anymore because the output of the Excel Services REST API is very different. This is an example:

[image: Example Table]

2010

```
            <div style="overflow: hidden">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ewr-sheettable" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: -2px; margin-top: -2px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; width: 1px; font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px;">
                        <div class="clp">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 101px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 101px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 96px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 96px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 112px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 112px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 76px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 76px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 96px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 96px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 76px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 76px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size: 1px; height: 1px; line-height: 1px; width: 98px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="width: 98px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; width: 1px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="height: 19px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="A3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px;">Test Column 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="B3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Test Column 2</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="C3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px;">Test Column 3</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="D3" style="font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;" />
                    <td data-range="E3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Test Column 4</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="F3" style="font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;" />
                    <td data-range="G3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-top: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px;">Test Column 5</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; width: 1px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="height: 19px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="A4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px;">Value1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="B4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Value2</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="C4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px;">Value3</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="D4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 74px; max-height: 19px;">Value4</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="E4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Value5</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="F4" style="font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;" />
                    <td data-range="G4" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px;">Value6</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; width: 1px;">
                        <div class="clp" style="height: 19px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="A5" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px;">Value7</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="B5" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Value8</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="C5" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px;">Value9</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="D5" style="font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;" />
                    <td data-range="E5" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px;">Value10</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-range="F5" style="font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;" />
                    <td data-range="G5" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; font: normal 11pt 'Calibri'; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-right: solid 1px #DADCDD; border-bottom: solid 1px #DADCDD;">
                        <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px;">Value11</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

2013

```
            <div style="overflow: hidden">
            <div class="ewr-sheettable" style="position: relative; width: 662px; height: 60px; font: normal 11pt Calibri,'Segoe UI',Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif; color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">
                <div id="grvl" style="position: absolute; height: 60px; width: 662px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 101px; left: 0px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 96px; left: 102px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 112px; left: 199px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 76px; left: 312px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 96px; left: 389px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 76px; left: 486px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 60px; border-right: 1px solid #dadcdd; width: 98px; left: 563px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="grhl" style="position: absolute; height: 60px; width: 662px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; width: 662px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dadcdd; top: 0px; height: 19px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; width: 662px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dadcdd; top: 20px; height: 19px;"></div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; width: 662px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dadcdd; top: 40px; height: 19px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="Div1" style="position: absolute; height: 60px; width: 662px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                    <div class="ewr-nglr" style="position: absolute; width: 662px; top: 0px; height: 19px;">
                        <div style="left: 0px; width: 101px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Test Column 1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 102px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Test Column 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 199px; width: 112px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Test Column 3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 389px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Test Column 4</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 563px; width: 98px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Test Column 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ewr-nglr" style="position: absolute; width: 662px; top: 20px; height: 19px;">
                        <div style="left: 0px; width: 101px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 102px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 199px; width: 112px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 312px; width: 76px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 74px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value4</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 389px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 563px; width: 98px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ewr-nglr" style="position: absolute; width: 662px; top: 40px; height: 19px;">
                        <div style="left: 0px; width: 101px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 99px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value7</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 102px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value8</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 199px; width: 112px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 110px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value9</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 389px; width: 96px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 94px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value10</div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="left: 563px; width: 98px; position: absolute; height: 19px;">
                            <div class="cv-nwl" style="width: 96px; max-height: 19px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: left;">Value11</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The worst is that the structure of the table is lost in the output of 2013, and is very difficult rebuilt it, even for word 2013. This is an screen shot of the table pasted in Word 2013:
[image: Result in Word 2013]

Is there anyway of configure or override by code some module in Sharepoint 2013 for get the same output of 2010?

Thanks in advance!